# Non-blocking socket with TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, nonblocking, packet

I'm writing a program using Java non-blocking socket and TCP. I understand that TCP is a stream protocol but the underlayer IP protocol uses packets. When I call SocketChannel.read(ByteBuffer dst), will I always get the whole content of IP packets? or it may end at any position in the middle of a packet?

This matters because I'm trying to send individual messages through the channel, each messages are small enough to be sent within a single IP packet without being fragmented. It would be cool if I can always get a whole message by calling read() on the receiver side, otherwise I have to implement some method to re-assembly the messages.

Edit: assume that, on the sender side, messages are sent with a long interval(like 1 second), so they aren't going to group together in one IP packet. On the receiver side, the buffer used to call read(ByteBuffer dst) is big enough to hold any message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream of bytes. Each read will receive between 1 and the maximum of the buffer size that you supplied and the number of bytes that are available to read at that time.

TCP knows nothing of your concept of messages. Each send by client can result in 0 or more reads being required at the other end. Zero or more because you might get a single read that returns more than one of your 'messages'.

You should ALWAYS write your read code such that it can deal with your message framing and either reassemble partial messages or split multiple ones.

You may find that if you don't bother with this complexity then your code will seem to 'work' most of the time, don't rely on that. As soon as you are running on a busy network or across the internet, or as soon as you increase the size of your messages you WILL be bitten by your broken code.

I talk about TCP message framing some more here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/message-framing-a-length-prefixed-packet-echo-server.html and here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/more-complex-message-framing.html though it's in terms of a C++ implementation so it may or may not be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

The socket API makes no guarantee that send() and recv() calls correlate to datagrams for TCP sockets. On the sending side, things may get regrouped already, e.g. the system may defer sending one datagram to see whether the application has more data; on the receiving side, a read call may retrieve data from multiple datagrams, or a partial datagram if the size specified by the caller is requires breaking packet.

IOW, the TCP socket API assumes you have a stream of bytes, not a sequence of packets. You need make sure you keep calling read() until you have enough bytes for a request.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`SocketChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) documentation:

```
A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for example, cannot read 
any more bytes than are immediately available from the socket's input buffer;
```

So if your destination buffer is large enough, you are supposed to be able to consume the whole data in the socket's input buffer.